# Google Colab RAM allocation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

iam new to google colab and have recently started using it.
Whenever i start colab session iam allocated with some RAM, which is very less out of available limit.(Please see attached image)
Could anyone suggest how to increase this allocated RAM?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O34gX.jpg)

Comment: Only 0.72 Gb out of 12Gb is available

Comment: Google Colaboratory is a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're reading it wrong, you are using .72G of the available 12G